# scala-breeze/spark replace a row of a densematrix with another densevector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, breeze, apache-spark-ml, scala-breeze

I have a breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix:

```
breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] =  
1  5  9  
2  6  10  
3  7  11  
4  8  12
```

and a breeze.linalg.DenseVector:

```
breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Int] = DenseVector(13, 14, 15)
```

Slicing allows me to get a particular row of a DenseMatrix but not replace/reassign it. How can I replace one of the rows(for eg. 2nd row) of the matrix with the vector to get something as shown below?

```
1  5  9  
13 14 15  
3  7  11  
3  8  12
```

Also, is there a way to achieve such matrix manipulations using any of Spark's matrix types? If yes, that would be much more desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Slicing allows me to get a particular row of a DenseMatrix but not replace/reassign

It does, you just need a correct shape - row slice is transposed

```
val m = DenseMatrix((1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12))

// breeze.linalg.Transpose[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Int]] = Transpose(DenseVector(10, 11, 12))
```

so you need matching transposed vector

```
val v = DenseVector(10, 11, 12)
m(1, ::) := v.t
m

// breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] =
// 1   5   9
// 10  11  12
// 3   7   11
// 4   8   12
```

> Also, is there a way to achieve such matrix manipulations using any of Spark's matrix types? If yes, that would be much more desirable.

Spark `ml.linalg` and `mllib.linalg` are not full featured linear algebra tools and exist mostly to support other `ml` / `mllib` functions, so slicing, and modifications are not supported. You'll have to access underlying `RDD` and transform data manually with joins.

Comment: Works for me! Important takeaways for noobs like me:  1. Use elementwise assignment operator instead of assignment (:= instead of =)  2. A row slice is a transposed vector by default!

Comment: Could you prominently highlight the fact that elementwise assignment operator needs to be used? It is such a big thing which people can miss.

Comment: Thanks! Your Q&A should be included in the Scala/Breeze cookbook!